# KeyError: 'view_class' in Flask-restplus. Routing not working

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restplus

According to the official documentation [page](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api), routes are initiated this way. I have done the same thing with the code below but for some reason, I get a `KeyError: 'view_class'`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app=app)


@api.route('/')
@api.route('/api')
class Root(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'message': 'it works'}, 200


@api.route('/test')
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code, change the `Root` class name to anything else. I've verified this fixes your problem. Unfortunately I don't see how that specific class name causes an issue based on reading the [Flask-RESTPlus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus) source. Sounds like you may have found a bug.

Comment: Seems like a bug

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple routes to the same resources then you can do as in this example: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/.

Comment: I just deleted `@api.route('/api')` and the error still persists so it can't be that causing the error